# If i paint each half of a picture with a different color, which color will be in the middle?

Tags: logic

I'm asking this on logic and didn't saw anything similar anywhere else. Well let's suppose, a 100px image, 50% of it(50px) will be purple and the another 50% will be violet. Which color will be in the middle? 50% is purple and the another 50% is violet, so 100% of the image has colors.

Comment: If every pixel is defined to be in of one of the halves, then how do you define the middle?

Comment: To me, purple and violet are equivalent, so it is easy to say that the middle will be purlet.

Comment: I have two numbers.  The left one is odd, and the right number is even.  What can we say about the number "in the middle"?  Perhaps your "color... in the middle" will be the color of the paper you print the image on?

Comment: It shouldn't as 100% of the image has colors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In math you have to define what happens on the boundary line.  If you view the square as $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ where the square brackets indicate that $0$ and $1$ are included in the interval, saying you paint the left half of the square purple and the right half violet only tells me that $[0,\frac 12)$ is purple and $(\frac 12,1]$ is violet.  The language is not precise enough to say what happens exactly at the middle.  You could define it either way by putting a square bracket on one of the two, or you could define that it never gets colored, or whatever you want.

In computer images you can think of there being a line between pixels (infinitely thin if you want) that never gets a color and the question does not arise.

Comment: This infinitely thin line is what doesn't make sense to me, as the image was painted 100%, it's like if that's between the two half(and there's no logic as nothing should be there), but the middle should be at the pixel 50, as one half of 100 is 50, what wouldn't make sense too, as that's inside the first half.

Comment: The pixels $1-50$ are one color and $51-100$ are the other.  There is no pixel in the middle.  If you had $99$ pixels we would know that $1-49$ were one color and $51-99$ were the other.  What happens to $50$ would have to be defined.  The existing language does not say.